# Suggestions for Dashboard with Many Numbers (VideoWall)

Tags: fonts

i'm working with power plant operation and we have a screen in videowall with all machine data, that is there are many numbers. Example:

> [image]

Can you give me suggestions for the best fonts to use on similar dashboards?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The image link doesn't work: https://ibb.co/XD23J4d

Comment: Apparently ibb.co doesn't allow hot linking. I embedded the image for you. Be aware, in my opinion, this is *way too opinion-based*. It amounts to "idea farming" which is kind of off topic.

Comment: How about *not* italic? The units are far easier to read than the names.

Comment: @Scott, i would really like opinions because i have no training or experience in developing this type of dashboard. I would like to know if it would be possible to improve it

Comment: I understand what you want..... but that is still sort of off topic here. There's no "right" or "wrong" answer to "what font should I use?" - merely opinions. You *might* try asking in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)... you can get *opinion* there.

Comment: Biggest readability improvements: 1. Use a non-serif for the capitalized headers. 2. if possible switch to anti-aliased font rendering. If not possible then don’t do italic on the labels.

Comment: @Scott, ok, thanks!